# Input não aceita texto - React

Tags: javascript, html, react

Sou novo no React mas creio que não seja algo do tipo próprio React. Estou efetuando um envio de formulário para enviar e registrar no meu banco de dados nos campos de input como demonstra nos códigos abaixo, porém, na tela ele não me permite inserir texto no input "Título do caso". Mesmo alterando os valores de minhas variáveis, ainda sim retorna um erro de inputs indefinido.

Segue meus código do React:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import{ FiArrowLeft } from 'react-icons/fi';

import api from '../../services/api';

import './styles.css';

import logoImg from '../../assets/logo.svg';


export default function NewIncident() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const history = useHistory();

    const ongId = localStorage.getItem('ongId');


    async function handleNewIncident(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const data=  {
            title,
            description,
            value
        };

        try {
            await api.post('incidents', data, {
                headers: {
                    Auth: ongId
                }
            });

            history.push('/profile');
        } catch(err) {
            alert('Não foi possível criar um novo caso, tente novamente');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="new-incident-container">
            <div className="content">
                <section>
                    <img src={logoImg} alt="Be The Hero"/>

                    <h1>Cadastrar novo caso</h1>
                    <p>Descreva o caso detalhadamente para encontrar um herói para resolver isso.</p>

                    <Link className="back-link" to="/profile">
                        <FiArrowLeft size={16} color="#E02041" />
                        Voltar para home
                    </Link>
                </section>

                <form onSubmit = {handleNewIncident} >

                    <input placeholder="Título do caso" value = {title} onChange = {e => setTitle(e.target.title)} />
                    <textarea placeholder="Descrição" value = {description} onChange = {e => setDescription(e.target.description)} />
                    <input placeholder="Valor em reis (R$)" value = {value} onChange = {e => setValue(e.target.value)} />

                    <button className="button" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

O erro que eu indentifiquei foi que quando você dá o `setValue()`, você está usando `e.target.title` em vez de `e.target.value` e o mesmo ocorre com o `e.target.description`, já que `title` e `description` não existe no componente `HTMLInputElement` do HTML.

Para você resolver, basta trocar `title` e `description` por `value`, ficando assim:

```
<input
    placeholder="Título do caso"
    value={title}
    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
/>
<textarea
    placeholder="Descrição"
    value={description}
    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
/>
<input
    placeholder="Valor em reis (R$)"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

No caso que você colocou `e.target.value`, é a forma correta, já que você quer o `valor` do `input` :D

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!